# "aurelia-polyfills" doesn't work (or we cannot import it correctly)

Tags: aurelia

We are using Aurelia JS in our project.
On IE11 we get error conntected to missing "includes" method:
*Object doesn't support property or method 'includes'*

We've installed *aurelia-polyfills* plugin but it doens't work (or we use it in wrong way).

In main-webpack.js:

```
...
import 'aurelia-polyfills';
...

bootstrap(function (aurelia) {
    aurelia.use
        .standardConfiguration()
        .defaultResources()
        .developmentLogging()
        ...
        .plugin(PLATFORM.moduleName('aurelia-polyfills'));

    aurelia.start().then(() => aurelia.setRoot(PLATFORM.moduleName('app-webpack'), document.body));
});
```

Our import statement is correct?
Should we do it in the same file?

Comment: I think I saw a question similar like this recently in Aurelia discourse forum. Have you had a look at that?

Comment: Yes, it was mine :]

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED:
*aurelia-polyfills* handles only *includes* for Array object, not String.
My error concerned on String, so I needed to create separate JS file with polyfill and use this code snippet: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes